# Puppeteer's page.goto(url) fails, I want to close the page/exit gracefully so my other JEST tests can continue to run

Tags: javascript, selenium-chromedriver, jestjs, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I have a test suite with Jest and Puppeteer hooked up for headless e2e testing. I set it up so running 'npm test' will run my Puppeteer tests first and then will run the rest of my tests.

Let's say the URL is unavailable. e.g. no internet connection or I forgot to serve it up. I want to exit my Puppeteer tests gracefully and not crash and burn.

```
page.goto('http://localhost:8000')
// above will fail and I want a way to know it failed to load that.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) to catch any errors thrown by [`page.goto()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options).

Then, you can use [`page.close()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagecloseoptions) and/or [`browser.close()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browserclose) to gracefully end Puppeteer:

```
try {
  await page.goto('http://localhost:8000');
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
  await page.close();
  await browser.close();
  process.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: What does process.exit do? Will this close/end even if there is no error?

Comment: @Ernesto `process.exit()` exits the current nodeJS process explicitly. Check out the doc here: [link](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit)

It will still exit even if there is no error after your script runs successfully. just be sure to call `browser.close()` at the end of successful script.